# Calculate total upon inserting data in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I would like to add the price and amount as total upon inserting it into SQLite db.
I've tried the below, but it didn't work.

```
INSERT INTO product (name, price, amount, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?, (price + amount))
```

Comment: what means "doesn't work"? should total be price * amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic approach is to use a [view](https://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) that computes the values of extra columns, and query it instead of the base table:

```sql
sqlite> CREATE TABLE raw_product(name, price, amount);
sqlite> CREATE VIEW product(name, price, amount, total) AS SELECT name, price, amount, price * amount FROM raw_product;
sqlite> INSERT INTO raw_product VALUES ('Widget', 1.50, 100);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM product;
name    price  amount  total 
------  -----  ------  -----
Widget  1.5    100     150.0
```

A newer way (Since Sqlite 3.31) is to use a [generated column](https://sqlite.org/gencol.html) instead, which lets you include computed values in the table itself instead of wrapping it in a view:

```sql
sqlite> CREATE TABLE product(name, price, amount, total AS (price * amount));
sqlite> INSERT INTO product VALUES ('Widget', 1.50, 100);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM product;
name    price  amount  total 
------  -----  ------  -----
Widget  1.5    100     150.0
```

There are options you can play with to control if the value is computed each time it's requested, or if it's materialized in the database and updated when other fields of the given row are. See the linked documentation for details.

Comment: Used multiplication instead of addition because that makes more sense for a column named 'total'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your brilliant idea showed above worked.